# Nginx Reverse-Proxy Only Working With Curl

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, server, reverse-proxy

I'm configuring my backend using nginx as a reverse-proxy for my node/express server, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Right now, if I use curl to ping my site (dcdocs.app) I get the following headers:

```
curl -I https://dcdocs.app 


HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Sat, 24 Nov 2018 03:32:24 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 388
x-powered-by: Express
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=0
last-modified: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 15:35:12 GMT
etag: W/"184-1672c9c7c51"
```

Using curl, the response body also returns my expected index file. However, when I visit this page on a web browser, I don't get any response.

Here's how I currently have my nginx.conf file configured:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto; # Spawn one process per core... To see #, use command nproc

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # Number of concurrent requests per worker... To see #, use command ulimit -n
}

http {

  include mime.types;

  server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name dcdocs.app;

    index index.html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dcdocs.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dcdocs.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

What is causing the problem here? What am I missing that's causing the page to not load in a browser? The browser currently just *hangs* if you try to visit the site.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe your browser is not HTTP2 compatible ?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Would more detail be helpful somehow?

Comment: You can use the developer tools by pressing F12 key, maybe you'll see what's happening.

Comment: looking for same issue. Did you get a solution.